# How to get a xml tag with attribute name

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get the value (number 21.48) from the field "NMONTHLYINSTALMENT" with PHP simple_xml.

This is my PHP code and XML:

```
$xml->data->struct("var[@name='NMONTHLYINSTALMENT']")->number

<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/>
    <data>
      <struct>
        <var name='UWEBSHOPID'><string>6FF1633B-6AE0-4AB6-A19E-D934B7DF783F</string></var>
        <var name='NMONTHLYINSTALMENT'><number>21.48</number></var>
        <var name='CCOMMAND'><string>GetMonthlyInstalment</string></var>
        <var name='NDURATION'><string>48</string></var>
        <var name='NPRICE'><string>825.89</string></var>
        <var name='COUTPUTTYPE'><string>XML</string></var>
      </struct>
    </data>
</wddxPacket>
```

I can not get it to work! Any help is much appriciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can do that with `xpath`. See my answer and demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606958/how-to-get-a-xml-tag-with-attribute-name/23607032#23607032)

Comment: Why not use php's own wddx support? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wddx-deserialize.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/bo69HSfy)**

You can use following;

```
<?php

$xml_str = <<< EOT
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/>
    <data>
      <struct>
        <var name='UWEBSHOPID'><string>6FF1633B-6AE0-4AB6-A19E-D934B7DF783F</string></var>
        <var name='NMONTHLYINSTALMENT'><number>21.48</number></var>
        <var name='CCOMMAND'><string>GetMonthlyInstalment</string></var>
        <var name='NDURATION'><string>48</string></var>
        <var name='NPRICE'><string>825.89</string></var>
        <var name='COUTPUTTYPE'><string>XML</string></var>
      </struct>
    </data>
</wddxPacket>
EOT;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);
$result = $xml->xpath('//data/struct/var[@name="NMONTHLYINSTALMENT"]/number');

echo $result[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

use DomDocument and xml path

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->Load("xmlfileName.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$path=$xpath->query("//data/struct/var[@name="NMONTHLYINSTALMENT"]/number")->item(0);
$doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: You can cast the result in Xpath. This avoids problems if the element is not found. Try: `var_dump($xpath->evaluate("number(//data/struct/var[@name="NMONTHLYINSTALMENT"]/number)"));`